# Simple Linear Program Problem in Constrained Optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Here is a subproblem I am having difficulties with:

$$d = \arg\min_x \ c^Tx$$ subject to $$x: \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 0,\quad  x_i \ge -b_i$$ for some $b \in \mathbb R^n$.

So I'm looking for an explicit solution for $d$.

I imagine, to an optimizer, this is a trivial linear program, but I'm really out of my league here and struggling to find resources to solve his problem. Any pointing in the right direction would be **greatly** appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @Stefanos Sorry, I'm a mechanical engineer, not a mathematician, so please bare with me :P. Please see my edit, you were right. And I'm looking for x that minimizes that function, not the function value.

Comment: @Stefanos Right, sorry that was just a typo. I think I've framed the problem properly now. Again, it's a subproblem, if you're wondering why $b_i$ has a negative sign in front of it.

Comment: @Stefanos ha, thanks for your edits! Any insight?

Comment: @Stefanos Ok! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I did not help much...